# How can i store value in variable after resolve promises state

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to access of `private_key` `variable` on `console.log` but while i am passing this value there result is showing is `promise{pending}` on console.

```
let private_key=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{     
 setTimeout(function(){
 resolve('464f64f6f464gs64g');

 },5000);
});

private_key.then((message)=>{
  return message;
});
console.log(private_key);
```

So how can i store value in variable and access it.

Comment: private_key is a promise,what do you want ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what are you trying to achieve, but `console.log(message);` in `.then()` will log the message after execution of  `setTimeout()`

Comment: i want to access of private_key value (464f64f6f464gs64g) after some time interval.

Comment: you can access it inside the `.then()` block.

Comment: if there are any other way possible for the same result ,please guide me.

Comment: you can use `console.log(await private_key)`, provided the function in which the code is called is `async`

Comment: @AkashDathan await can only be used inside an async function. Also its experimental and not well supported atm. The major browsers support it for few weeks/months now though.

Comment: yeah true, I have mentioned that it should be an async function. And I think  its the only alternative for writing code inside `then` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the resolved value in the `then` block.

You can also access the `value` once it is resolved by adding another `then` block.

```js
let private_key=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{     
 setTimeout(function(){
  resolve('464f64f6f464gs64g');
 },5000);
});

private_key
      .then( message => console.log(message));
      
private_key
  .then( message => message)
  .then(key => console.log(key));
```

You can also use `async-await`.

```js
let getKey = async () => {
  let private_key = new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {     
   setTimeout(() => resolve('464f64f6f464gs64g'),5000);
  });

  var key = await private_key;
  console.log(key);
}

getKey();
```

Comment: Or you just log it in the first then which would be cleaner.

Comment: Added both of the example.

Comment: thanks @HassanImam but could u guide me , is it possible to access key variable outside of promise end. i want to only value of key variable so that i am passing to another function for further requirement.

Comment: Then you should use `async-await`, but it will require you to wrap your statements. Also, you can pass around promises .

Comment: hi, @HassanImam, I really did fail to understand the advantage of the 1st method, I mean how could I make good use of it

Answer (score 0):

You are getting promise{pending} because you have written non-blocking code and the promise will be resolved after 5 sec.so the execution will move downward and try to log private_key but as the promise is not resolved it will show pending.
You can write your code like this

```
let private_key=new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{     
setTimeout(function(){
resolve('464f64f6f464gs64g');

},5000);
});

private_key.then((message)=>{
console.log(message);
});
```